# Why does a computer slow down when left running for a long time without restarting?

Tags: linux, windows, windows-10, performance, operating-systems

I am currently using Windows and see that I need to reboot my PC time to time, without which it feels slow. That is if I keep running it for 4 - 8 hours without restarting, it'll start to slow down even if I close all the programs that I was using. This degradation in performance with uptime is something that I have primarily experienced on Windows. During my work on Linux, I did not observe such issues. Wanted to understand what might be causing the degradation of performance with uptime on Windows ? Also, is there something that can be done to improve on / avoid this behavior ?

If needed, my machine is a Dell Precision 5540, with an intel i7 9th Gen, it has 16 GB if RAM and a 512 GB SSD. There's a Nvidia Quadro T1000 GPU as a dedicated GPU.

Comment: it is not normal for a correctly specced windows 10 PC to slow down after only 4-8 hours. you most likely have either mispecced or malfunctioning hardware or bad software.

Answer (score 0):

Some badly written software leaks memory, and accumulated wasted resources can slow things down.

On machines which manage their clock speed and power, the system will also slow down if it starts getting hotter than is safe for the processor chip. But that's really more a matter of it being able to cheat a bit and run faster when cold.

Also, if your measurements depend on network transfer speed, it's not uncommon for ISPs to allow brief bursts of activity to run at full speed and then "throttle" your data rate if you start tying up a lot of resources for a longer time.

There may be other causes. To find out why *you* are experiencing a slowdown, someone has to look at your machine and how you are using it.